# STL algorithms + c'tors don't work anymore for raw pointers to C arrays because of pointing one past end

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, stl

I just ran into an issue with my compiler settings ("-Werror") in combination with using raw pointers to C-style arrays as STL iterators. I get an

```
array_bounds_problem.cc:12:36: error: array subscript is above array bounds [-Werror=array-bounds]
     const int*  p = std::find(vals, vals + (sizeof(vals)/sizeof(vals[0]))+1, 12);
                           ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

The problem is that for using STL algorithms/constructors using a pair of iterators that the `end` iterator must be pointing one-past-the-end ... which is *indeed* outside e.g. the storage of a C-style array.

An example is here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/59ad7b82fe63211d

Any ideas how I can compile with "-Werror" and still use C-style arrays mixed with STL algorithms/containers??

**EDIT**

Right! Thanks a *lot* for the answers!
Unfortunately I cannot use `std::array` / `std::begin()/end()` because the code must be compatible with pre C++11 :-(
(we have to support (very) old systems ...)

[tobi303](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47439279/26083) and Omnifarious's suggestions are obviously what's happening ...
I fell for the age old off-by-one error. I feel very stupid now.

Cheers!

Comment: `std::begin(vals)` and `std::end(vals)` should be well defined as long as `vals` is an array and not just a pointer.

Comment: Have you considered just using a [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead?

Comment: @François Andrieux is right, std::end not only gets rid of the warning, it is also much more readable: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a8c7fa79c91b405c

Comment: The error is in your code, not with the way iterators work. Since ANSI C the standard has always said that a pointer or an index has a well-defined value when it points to one past the end. So, if that's where you were pointing, you wouldn't get that error. But, you aren't. You're pointing two past the end. You don't need the +1 there. `val[size]` (aka `val + size`) is one past the end. Valid elements are 0 through size - 1, which is size elements.

Comment: I understand having to support very old processors and OS's, why do you have to support very old _compilers_?

Comment: Because the systems are not under our control; we don't own nor maintain them. We have to assume only the compiler that was shipped with the O/S is available. For Debian that can be quite old - only /recently/ our users switched from Debian Etch to Debian Wheezy ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
vals + vals.size + 1
```

is one past one past the end (or two past the end). The last pointer in the array is

```
vals + vals.size - 1
```

hence one past the end should be

```
vals + vals.size
```

If you fix this in your code, [the warning is gone and it compiles](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/78146a7f35bc1a20).

However, consider using `std::begin()` and `std::end()` or simply a `std::array`. That syntax to get the size of a C style array is so horrible that I allowed myself to use a short way of writing it above.